# using CodeDom create a generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, methods, codedom

I want to create a generic method using codedom..
I have tried this code

```
foreach (MethodInfo mhttem in sMethodName)
{
     var mth = new CodeMemberMethod();
     mth.Name = mhttem.Name;
     mth.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference(mhttem.ReturnType.Name);
     foreach (var param in mhttem.GetParameters())
     {
         mth.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(param.ParameterType, param.Name)); 
     }
}
```

but in the method parameter , namespace is also displayed.
for eg..

```
    ReminderTemplate GeTemplateById(System.Guid templateId);
```

I want only

```
    ReminderTemplate GeTemplateById(Guid templateId);
```

here                                                                                mth.Parameters.Add(new               CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(param.ParameterType.Name, param.Name));

but if i have string type argument it converted to
String Class

for eg

```
      PendingEmail GetByEmailToSubjectBodyMsg(String emailTo, String subject, String bodyMsg);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I see you have updated the question with your attempt. don't worry `String` is same as `string` for C# compiler at least.

Comment: yes, but  
I require a string as a datatype

Comment: I think you confused generic methods with generated methods. The first is actually a method with a type parameter in it, which I cannot see in your GetTemplateById method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an hardcoded list of types in the `CSharpCodeGenerator` that will be translated to equivalent C# types. These extension methods will translate a fullname of a type (namespace + name) stripping it of the namespace if the fullname isn't one of the C# recognized types.

```
public static class CSharpCodeDomExtensions
{
    // Taken from CSharpCodeGenerator.GetBaseTypeOutput(CodeTypeReference typeRef)
    private static readonly HashSet<string> BaseTypes = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "system.int16", "system.int32", "system.int64", 
        "system.string", "system.object", "system.boolean", "system.void", 
        "system.char", "system.byte", 
        "system.uint16", "system.uint32", "system.uint64", 
        "system.sbyte", 
        "system.single", "system.double", "system.decimal"
    };

    private static bool IsBaseType(string fullName)
    {
        // It is done in this way in CSharpCodeGenerator.GetBaseTypeOutput
        return BaseTypes.Contains(fullName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim());
    }

    public static string StripNameSpaces(this Type type)
    {
        string fullName = type.FullName;

        if (IsBaseType(fullName))
        {
            return fullName;
        }

        return type.Name;
    }

    public static string StripNameSpaces(this string fullName)
    {
        if (IsBaseType(fullName))
        {
            return fullName;
        }

        return fullName.Split('.').Last();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
mth.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(param.ParameterType.StripNamespaces(), param.Name));
```

Note that there are disadvantages on stripping namespaces: you must be sure to have included the "right" namespace in the `CodeDom` and you could have multiple classes that share the same namespace. Other problem: you can't distinguish between `OuterClass.InnerClass` and `Namespace.OuterClass`. No check can be easily done on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Name` property of [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) class to avoid fully qualified name of the type.

```
mth.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(param.ParameterType.Name, param.Name));
```

Comment: like ..                                                                                                                                  `PendingEmail GetByEmailToSubjectBodyMsg(String emailTo, String subject, String bodyMsg);`                                                                                      I want ........                                                                                                `PendingEmail GetByEmailToSubjectBodyMsg(string emailTo, string subject, string bodyMsg);`